# HTML Email isn't centered, aligned left to the border. How do I fix?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, alignment

I am typing out html email, on my editor (Dreamweaver) and on Chrome everything is laid out perfectly, but once I send it out via Gmail all of the text hugs right to the left hand side of the email. Anyone know how to fix this?

I have attached the  code and inline CSS - I can attach the  code if it helps. I've tried a few things but I don't know the correct way to fix it that would suit multiple email clients such as gmail, yahoo and the rest - some work for one or two but not all.

[email from Gmails point of vew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hQVi.png)
[email from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TFFx.png)

```html
<body width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #FBFBFB;">
  <center style="width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
    <!--[if mso | IE]>
    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #222222;">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
    <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: sans-serif;">
      Raise money for drought angels!
    </div>
    <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->

    <!-- Create white space after the desired preview text so email clients don’t pull other distracting text into the inbox preview. Extend as necessary. -->
    <!-- Preview Text Spacing Hack : BEGIN -->
    <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: sans-serif;">
      &zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;
    </div>
    <!-- Preview Text Spacing Hack : END -->

    <!-- Set the email width. Defined in two places:
            1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 600px.
            2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 600px width. -->

    <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; " class="email-container">
      <!--[if mso]>
            <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->

      <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
      <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto; background-color: #F9F9F9;">
        <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: #F9F9F9;">
            <div style="position: relative; text-align: center; color: white;">
              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GU6Yziw-9AU6RpiYAdsTh2oPiw_qbf5YI74UaQdYogREfYSfQeZCrq49fZtTSvzF3L2lupolMSxDX1Nj_omF4o-SSBtkPwWrLoXZcvsAcDEWrE8414h6S1AkcI73KEU2q1F1vHIHug=w2400" width="600" height="" alt="Nielsen Header Banner" border="0"
                style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; background: #F9F9F9; font-family: open sans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #333333; margin: auto;" class="g-img">

            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Hero Image, Flush : END -->
        <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
        <br><br><br>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: ##F9F9F9;">
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="75%">
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px; font-family: open sans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;  line-height: 20px; color: #333333;">
                  <h3 style="margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px;"><br><br>Food is love, spread the love!</h3>
                  <h3 style="margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px;"> </h3>
                  <p style="margin: 0; "> <br>Do you have any treasured family recipes you would love to share? </p> <br>
                  <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="80%">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding-bottom: 10px; font-family: open sans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;  line-height: 20px; color: #333333;">
                        <ol>
                          <ul>
                            <li>From sweet to savoury and anything inbetween!</li>
                            <li>Must have detailed instructions&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                            <li>Must be an original recipe&nbsp;</li>
                          </ul>
                        </ol>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <br>
                  <p style="margin: 0; ">We are creating a community cookbook full of your original recipes to raise money for Drought Angels. To submit your recipe please download the template, fill in the details and send to stephanie.ngo@nielsen.com.</p>
                  <br>

                  <!-- Button : BEGIN -->

                  <!-- Button : END --><br>
                  <p style="margin: 0; color: #333333; font-weight: bold;">We look forward to seeing your recipes!</p><br>
                  <p style="margin: 0; color: #333333;">Steph, Claire, Ollie and Wendi</p>
                </td>
            </table>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->
          <tr>
            <td height="40"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- Email Body : END -->
      <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
      <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto; background-color: #F4F4F4; ">
        <tr>
          <td height="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 60%; padding: 10px; font-family: open sans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; color: #000000;">
              <p style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">Drought Angels – "a charity run by people with big hearts who are passionate about our farmers and keeping them on the land."</p><br>
              <p style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;"><a href="https://www.droughtangels.org.au/">https://www.droughtangels.org.au/</a>&nbsp;</p>
              <br><br>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </table>
      <!-- Email Footer : END -->
      <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </div>
    <!--[if mso | IE]>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<![endif]-->
  </center>
  <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
</body>
```

Comment: I would try removing `max-width: 600px;` and just set `width: 600px` and see if that works better. I think there are issues with `max-width` in HTML emails. Also, does class `email-container` have any styles associated with it?

Comment: Email container has min-width properties set in style of 320, 375 and 414px